# Is it possible to call functions in pymongo update operators?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I tried to add another field to documents in MongoDB using pyMongo. As a sample I got random users from [here](https://randomuser.me/) and I'm going to add another field into the 'registered' part :

```
from datetime import datetime
from pymongo import MongoClient 

client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client['metadata']
db.users.update_many({},
[{
    "$set":{
        "registered.newField" : "$registered.date"        
    }
}])
```

This is working perfectly but whenever I'm going to use another function and use the `"$registered.date"` as input parameter, it seems `"registered.date"` is not parsed anymore.

```
db.users.update_many({},
[{
    "$set":{    
        "registered.newField" : 
            datetime.strptime(
              "$registered.date" ,
              "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ").year 
    }
}])
```

this throw exception :

> time data '$registered.date' does not match format
>   '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'

this is how documents looks like :

```
 {
      "gender": "male",
      "name": {
        "title": "mr",
        "first": "brad",
        "last": "gibson"
      },    
      "registered": {
        "date": "2002-05-21T10:59:49.966Z",
        "age": 17
      },
      .....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not actually use programming language's function on an existing fields value in aggregation pipeline. So what does that mean ? - When you write something like :

```
db.users.update_many({},
[{
    "$set":{    
        "registered.newField" : 
            datetime.strptime(
              "$registered.date" ,
              "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ").year 
    }
}])
```

then the function at below line :

```
datetime.strptime( "$registered.date" , "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ").year
```

will be executed in application server & produce a result prior to query hits DB, So that result will be updated to `"registered.newField"` field. As this operation is taking place prior to hitting DB then your query will not be able to get `"$registered.date"` value. So the execution of `datetime.strptime().year` in python is actually considering `"$registered.date"` as a string rather-than getting field value & then converting it.
Since a string `"$registered.date"` is not of format "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ" that function will fail.

To test - I would say you can try to pass-in a hard-coded value to function like `datetime.strptime( "2002-05-21T10:59:49.966Z" , "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ").year` then `.update()` would certainly work.

**Resolution :**

As you're using that `datetime.strptime().year` just to get year then you actually take use of aggregation operators [$year](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/year/index.html#year-aggregation) :

```
db.users.update_many({}, [
  {
    $set: {
      "registered.newField": { $year: "$registered.date" }
    }
  }
]);
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oaiBEYcj39m)

I'm assuming your field `"$registered.date"` is of type `Date` something like `ISODate('2002-05-21T10:59:49.966Z')`, If in any case if it's type of string then use [$dateFromString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/#datefromstring-aggregation) to convert to `Date` & then get year :

```
db.users.update_many({}, [
  {
    $set: {
      "registered.newField": {
        $year: {
          $dateFromString: {
            dateString: "$registered.date"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/926iGREiHj1)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can absolutley call functions within a pymongo update; what you can't do is bend the rules in your example and rely on the `$` operator to get the previous stage value to pass into the function.

This code will work; if you have a huge dataset you can update with a bulk update in a similar manner.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import datetime
import pprint

db = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27019/")['mydatabase']

db.users.insert_one( {
      "gender": "male",
      "name": {
        "title": "mr",
        "first": "brad",
        "last": "gibson"
      },
      "registered": {
        "date": "2002-05-21T10:59:49.966Z",
        "age": 17
      }
})

for record in db.users.find():
    try:
        date_str = record['registered']['date']
    except KeyError:
        continue
    year = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ").year
    db.users.update_one({'_id': record['_id']}, {'$set': {'registered.newField': year}})

pprint.pprint(db.users.find_one())
```